# Is there any way to update a Power Automate variable inside a JS function?

Tags: javascript, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm using the action "Run JavaScript function on web page" for extracting day & month from a website. The problem is that the value returned by JS function (stored to DateVar as a power automate var) is treated as [object Object] by Power Automate.

Here is the JS code.

```
var dynamicSelector = '[data-test="qc-wrapper"]';
function extractAndConcatenateDate() {
  // Find the elements by the dynamic selector
  var cardElement = document.querySelector(dynamicSelector);

  if (!cardElement) {
    return 'Element not found';
  }

  // Find the elements by their class names or other attributes
  var dateElement = cardElement.querySelector('.sc-ABC1 .sc-XYZ1');
  var monthElement = cardElement.querySelector('.sc-ABC2 .sc-XYZ2');

  // Extract the text content from the elements
  var date = dateElement.textContent;
  var month = monthElement.textContent;

  // Return the concatenated date and month as a string
  return date + month;
}

// Call the function and return the concatenated date and month as a string
return extractAndConcatenateDate();
```

I need to get the return value as text.

Since, it is returning as an Object, I thought and tried out the following approach.

1. Create a new power automate variable using "Set variable" action: tempVar = "tempContent"
2. In the JS fn, added a statement ( '%tempVar%' = date+month; ) hoping the text content will be updated to this power automate variable.
3. Execute the "Run JavaScript function on web page".
4. But tempVar still contains "tempContent" only.

So far, I can see only two options:-

1. find a way to update tempVar inside JS function
2. find a way to get text value from the returned [object Object]

I also tried using JSON.stringify while returning but still no luck!

Please provide your suggestions on this problem using Power Automate Desktop Flow.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to a major problem with the 'Run Javascript function on web page' action. might be to do with this [Manivest V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-automate/desktop-flows/manifest#run-javascript-function-on-web-page-action)

It still seems to work to manipulate page content but not for returning values.
even something as simple as:

```
var dm = 'val';
WScript.Echo(dm);
```

doesn't work.

Another way of doing what you want is to add a UI Element, doesn't matter what element. Then use a variable that you assign the css selector value to, and then use the variable in the UI Element's Default Selector.

Using the 'Get details of element on web page' action you can then extract the text as needed.
(copy code to a PAD flow)

```
WebAutomation.LaunchChrome.AttachToChromeByUrl TabUrl: $'''https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/scheduler''' AttachTimeout: 5 BrowserInstance=> Browser
SET elementSelector TO $'''#scheduler > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > span'''
WebAutomation.GetDetailsOfElement BrowserInstance: Browser Control: appmask['Web Page \'https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/scheduler\'']['Span \'Today\''] AttributeName: $'''Own Text''' AttributeValue=> AttributeValue
SET Date TO AttributeValue
SET elementSelector TO $'''#scheduler > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div > div > table > tbody > tr > th:nth-child(1)'''
WebAutomation.GetDetailsOfElement BrowserInstance: Browser Control: appmask['Web Page \'https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/scheduler\'']['Span \'Today\''] AttributeName: $'''Own Text''' AttributeValue=> AttributeValue
SET Day TO AttributeValue
Display.ShowMessageDialog.ShowMessage Title: $'''combined''' Message: $'''%Date% - %Day%''' Icon: Display.Icon.None Buttons: Display.Buttons.OK DefaultButton: Display.DefaultButton.Button1 IsTopMost: False ButtonPressed=> ButtonPressed
```

It should look like this:

[image: flowView]

I'm not sure what you page looks like but I've used the [telerik scheduler demo site](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/scheduler) (month view) to explain this answer.

I added a UI element, seriously any element will do.
[image: UIElement]

Edit the UI Element and flip the Text editor switch.
Then set the Default Selector value to the variable.
[image: UIElementEdit]

the result is a popup showing the 2 values in a popup.

[image: combinedResultPopup]

It is a pain that the Javascript action doesn't work, but this is at least an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took reference from it and used "Extract data from web page" action to get the expected data.